# Proper use of NSDateFormatter?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

I'm trying to get a string with the current date using the following:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

However NSLog is not outputting any strings (I'm getting a blank in the console)? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have to tell the date formatter the output format you want to use. For example:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

See the documentation for more (e.g. `setDateFormat:`). Sorry for not mentioning this in my other answer.

Comment: That's alright, you've actually been really helpful on a lot of my questions so thanks.